# Mongoose to swagger : <field> validation failed /BSONTypeError Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to build a REST api using Express ,mongoose and Swagger for API documentation. for Swagger schema i have used mongoose-to-swagger package to directly convert my existing schema to swagger. The issue is swagger is adding extra "_id" field in schema as show in image.

[image: The extra "_id"s]

Also when i try to post a new user it is giving me an error :

ValidationError: Buyer validation failed: Buyer_Delivery_Address._id: Cast
to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type number) at path "_id" because of "BSONTypeError"

reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

_message: 'Buyer validation failed'

How can i resolve this issue ?

> The App.js

`

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const m2s = require('mongoose-to-swagger');
const swaggerjsdocs = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const Buyer = require('./models/Buyer_model')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Ecommerce')

const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.log(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log("connected to database"))

app.use(express.json())

const buyer_schema =  m2s(Buyer)
const options ={
    definition:{
        openapi:'3.0.0',
        info:{
            title:"Ecommerce practice project",
            version:"1.0.0"
        },
        components: {   
            schemas: buyer_schema},
        servers:[
            {
               url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
            }],
        },
        apis:['./App.js']
    }


const swaggerSpec = swaggerjsdocs(options)


app.use('/api-docs',swaggerUi.serve,swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec))


console.log(buyer_schema.properties)

/**
 * @swagger
 * /:
 *  get:
 *      summary: The get method 
 *      description: the description of get
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: To test get method
 */
 app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("welcome to site")
})



/**
 * @swagger
 * /buyer:
 *  get:
 *      summary: The get data from database  
 *      description: displaying all data from database
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: success fullydisplaying all data from database
 *              content:
 *                  application/json:
 *                      schema:
 *                          type: array
 *                          items:
 *                              $ref: '#/components/schemas'
 * 
 */ 
app.get('/buyer', async (req,res) => {
    const buyers =  await Buyer.find()
    res.json(buyers)
    // res.send("welcome")
})

/**
 * @swagger
 * /buyer/{id}:
 *  get:
 *      summary: The get specific id data from database  
 *      description: displaying all data from database
 *      parameters:
 *          - in: path
 *            name: id
 *            required: true
 *            description: fetch with id number
 *            schema:
 *              type: integer
 *             
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: success fullydisplaying all data from database
 *              content:
 *                  application/json:
 *                      schema:
 *                          type: array
 *                          items:
 *                              $ref: '#/components/schemas'
 * 
 */ 

// getting one record
app.get('/buyer/:id',(req,res) => {
    
    
})

/**
 * @swagger
 * /buyer/newUser:
 *  post:
 *      summary: Update the data in database  
 *      description: Add the data in database
 *      requestBody:
 *          required: true
 *          content:
 *              application/json:
 *                  schema:
 *                      $ref: '#/components/schemas'
 *      responses:
 *          200:
 *              description: Added Successfully
 *              
 */ 

// creating one record
app.post('/buyer/newUser', async (req,res) => {
    
   
    const buyer = new Buyer({
        Buyer_name: req.body.Buyer_name,
        Buyer_Delivery_Address: req.body.Buyer_Delivery_Address,
        Buyer_Phone: req.body.Buyer_Phone,
        Buyer_Cart: req.body.Buyer_Cart
    })

    const newBuyer = await buyer.save()
    res.json(newBuyer);
    
})



// updating one record
app.patch('/buyer/:id',(req,res) => {
    
})



// deleting one record
app.delete('/buyer/:id',(req,res) => {
    
})


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Started"))
```

`

> Buyer_model.js
> `

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")


const buyerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Buyer_name : {
        type: String,
        
    },
    Buyer_Delivery_Address: { 
        type: {
            address_line: {type: String} , 
            City: {type:String}, 
            Postal_Code: {type:Number}, 
            Country: {type: String},
        },
        
    },
    Buyer_Phone: {
        type: Number,
        
    },
    Buyer_Cart: { 
        type: { 
            Product_ID: {type: Number}, 
            Product_Name: {type:String} , 
            Product_quantity: {type:Number}, 
            Product_Price: {type:Number} 
        },
        
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Buyer',buyerSchema)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/giddyinc/mongoose-to-swagger#meta-properties) you can pass an additional argument with omit property which takes an array of fields to omit. Also, haven't tried in nested model yet but should work fine after using omit property in all the nested models also.